# Object unions don't work as expected in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, union

Suppose I have a config interface and a variable which assigns the interface to it:

```
interface Config {
    plugins: {
        name1: {
            foo: boolean;
        },
        name2: {
            foo: boolean;
            bar: boolean;
        }
    }
}

const config: Config = {
    plugins: {
        name1: {
            foo: true,
        },
        name2: {
            foo: true,
            bar: false
        }
    }
}
```

And a type `Options` being a union containing all values from `plugins` property

```
type Options = Config["plugins"][keyof Config["plugins"]];
```

which TS translates to `{ foo: boolean } | { foo: boolean; bar: boolean }`
Now, when I try to use it, it fails:

```
const pluginOptions: Options = config.plugins.name2;
const foo = pluginOptions.foo;
const bar = pluginOptions.bar; // error here

// Property 'bar' does not exist on type 'Options'.
// Property 'bar' does not exist on type '{ foo: boolean; }'
```

However, raw object works..

```
const equal = JSON.stringify(config.plugins.name2) === JSON.stringify({ foo: true, bar: false });
console.log(equal); // true, identical objects!

const pluginOptions2: Options = { foo: true, bar: false };
const foo2 = pluginOptions2.foo;
const bar2 = pluginOptions2.bar;
```

If I add property `bar` to plugin `name1`, the error disappears.
My goal is to check if a correct object is passed to a variable, so in this case it should allow ONLY `{ foo: boolean }` or `{ foo: boolean; bar: boolean }`.
I have no idea why it is happening. I don't know why using `config.plugins.name2` doesn't work, but copying and pasting object works, even when they're both the same. Am i doing anything wrong here or is there any other way of achieving this?

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHsQ2Ac2QbwFgAoZM5ABwBsBXHUAZwC4CTz3kQ4BbCARhZFSHETHToWAI3FUIcEAG42I5AF8ANMpFdeAJkFaVZMROTT0s+UuFGykuFCky5iw+1WGPxLyQSYGYMh+WLgsGCF4ALysNpS09CDMMUY6-AaxRiYsYFA0EJoZ5Bpu5Kn6ybbG4tm5+SUi9o7I8FQMEPVqniQ+xCRgAJ4UKADyFGDA-sjR4dg4ANoARNR0jAsAunMA1hD96DBomLOLywkM62sKyAD0VwTN1WbO8mrIAD53WY8WLpeNTt-PHrBAJxFYgUbjfwsCETRJTIKHXAAOhOjCRZWswMCJnhqPBY1hDCRJkx-kCjVx8VAMP8SMalxuyGgUHQUBI7OIwO+SKo6BwAAoAFIAZWGADkkQEoKB6DB+vzgrMUVTEuieBBdABKKaRaIi8WSnIy4By-n4e6mHJ5dRmBwsFptNSa7WMq3tTlk0EJGmJco+hjw82fN02v7NOCtFCqUmJbHiXSUsH+3TE8QxkGNBPRPHJukOBm3EDoJlQFls4hAA)

Comment: The problem is that the type `{ foo: boolean } | { foo: boolean; bar: boolean }` means that the field `bar` might be or might not be present, depending on which version you receive. Typescript is warning you that you're accessing a property which might not be there.

Comment: @Etheryte I assigned the object to the variable `pluginOptions`, so shouldn't TS narrow types? Just like `const str = "something"; const strOrNum: string | number = str` does.

Comment: You've manually annotated the type to be wider by setting `const pluginOptions: Options = ...`.